# Proof that a strongly connected digraph has an irreducible adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, proof-writing

I need to prove that a strongly connected digraph has an irreducible adjacency matrix. If anybody would be willing to give an advice on how to tackle this problem I would be thankful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, you are using the following definition:

> The matrix $A$ is irreducible if it is not [reducible](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html).

In such a case, assume that the matrix is reducible, that is the state space of the graph allows for the decomposition $V = V_1\cup V_2$ where sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ are disjoint and
$$
  a_{ij} = 0 \tag{1}
$$
for all $i\in V_1$ and $j\in V_2$. Since $V$ is strongly connected, there exists a path $i_1i_2\dots i_n$ where $i_1$ is some point in $V_1$ and $i_2$ is some point in $V_2$. Show that it contradicts $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Assume that the matrix is reducible, let $V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_k$ be the vertices that form blocks in the reduced form of matrix (that is, it is upper triangular with respect to those blocks). Show that there is no edge $v_{k+l}\to v_k$ for $v_k \in V_k$ and $v_{k+l} \in V_{k+l}$ by observing that the related number in the matrix is 0 (zero).

Good luck!