# part of proof that strongly connected graph has an irreducible adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I'm coming from this thread: [Prove that a strongly connected digraph has an irreducible adjacency matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350994/prove-that-a-strongly-connected-digraph-has-an-irreducible-adjacency-matrix)
(can't ask in the comments there unfortunately) and there's one statement I can't prove:

"for all $i\in V_1$ and $j\in V_2$. Since $V$ is strongly connected, there exists a path $i_1i_2\dots i_n$ where $i_1$ is some point in $V_1$ and $i_2$ is some point in $V_2$."

how do I know there's always such a path?

Comment: What's the definition of "strongly connected"?

Comment: a graph is strongly connected if it contains a directed path between each pair of vertices (v,w) in it.

Comment: So what would a directed path between $i \in V_1$ and $j \in V_2$ look like?

Comment: There's a typo: he should have written "$i_n$ is some point in $V_2$"

Comment: woah okay, now it makes complete sense to me. could've figured myself.. been reading about this for hours nonstop, maybe I need a break.
thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: No problem. And get used to that, you're studying math.